# HashMap/Hashtable not returning int as key value in for loop

Tags: java, hashmap, hashtable

When I am trying to access map.get(c) in for loop (as shown in version 2), it returns null value and sets upper bound to be null, resulting in null-pointer exception. On the other hand, if I create end variable and assign it map.get(c) value (as shown in version 1), it works fine. So, would you please explain me why?

version 1: Works perfectly fine

```
    int count=0;
    int st=0;
    string s = "abcabcbb";

    Hashtable<Character, Integer> map = new Hashtable<Character, Integer>();

    char[] str = s.toCharArray();
    for(int i=0; i<str.length; i++){
        char c = str[i];
        if(map.get(c)==null){
            map.put(c, i);

            if(count < map.get(c) - st + 1){
                count = map.get(c) - st + 1;
            };
        }


        else {
            int end = map.get(c);     // End variable --> returns int value as expected

            for(int j=st; j<=end; j++){
                map.remove(str[j]);
                st = j+1;
            }
            map.put(c,i);
        }

    }

    System.out.println(count);
```

Version 2: Gives null-pointer exception

```
    int count=0;
    int st=0;
    string s = "abcabcbb";

    Hashtable<Character, Integer> map = new Hashtable<Character, Integer>();

    char[] str = s.toCharArray();
    for(int i=0; i<str.length; i++){
        char c = str[i];
        if(map.get(c)==null){
            map.put(c, i);

            if(count < map.get(c) - st + 1){
                count = map.get(c) - st + 1;
            };
        }


        else {
            //int end = map.get(c);     // End variable commented

            for(int j=st; j<=map.get(c); j++){   // replaced end w map.get(c) --> returns null instead of int
                map.remove(str[j]);
                st = j+1;
            }
            map.put(c,i);
        }

    }

    System.out.println(count);
```

Thanks for your help in advance!
Rohan.

Comment: Also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40471/differences-between-hashmap-and-hashtable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A for-loop runs until its condition is not met (in your case, until `j <= map.get(c)` is `false`). This condition is also **not cached**, as shown by the output of the code below:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (int i = 0; i < getCondition(); i++) {

    }
}

private static int getCondition() {
    System.out.println("Test");
    return 3;
}
```

Output:

```
Test
Test
Test
Test
```

For that reason, `map.get(c)` will be called for each iteration of the for-loop. If you happen to remove the entry with key `c` from `map`, then the value returned from `Map#get` is `null`, which is what causes the `NullPointerException`.