# How does resize works in Hash Map in Java?

Tags: java, algorithm, hash, hashmap

Here is the decompiled java code the method that is used to put an entry in the a hash map.

```
/**
     * Implements Map.putAll and Map constructor.
     *
     * @param m the map
     * @param evict false when initially constructing this map, else
     * true (relayed to method afterNodeInsertion).
     */
    final void putMapEntries(Map<? extends K, ? extends V> m, boolean evict) {
        int s = m.size();
        if (s > 0) {
            if (table == null) { // pre-size
                float ft = ((float)s / loadFactor) + 1.0F;
                int t = ((ft < (float)MAXIMUM_CAPACITY) ?
                         (int)ft : MAXIMUM_CAPACITY);
                if (t > threshold)
                    threshold = tableSizeFor(t);
            }
            else if (s > threshold)
                resize();
            for (Map.Entry<? extends K, ? extends V> e : m.entrySet()) {
                K key = e.getKey();
                V value = e.getValue();
                putVal(hash(key), key, value, false, evict);
            }
        }
    }
```

Where does this formula come from and how does it work ?

```
float ft = ((float)s / loadFactor) + 1.0F;
```

and also what is the meant of this method

```
/**
 * Returns a power of two size for the given target capacity.
 */
static final int tableSizeFor(int cap) {
    int n = -1 >>> Integer.numberOfLeadingZeros(cap - 1);
    return (n < 0) ? 1 : (n >= MAXIMUM_CAPACITY) ? MAXIMUM_CAPACITY : n + 1;
}
```

Comment: can you specify the java version, to check `tableSizeFor( cap )` - [HashMap](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48094803/5081877)

Answer (score 2):

`currentSize should <= capacity * loadFactor`, which means when `currentSize / loadFactor > capacity`, we should resize the map. The `+1` is used for round up.

As it comments, `tableSizeFor` is used for:

> Returns a power of two size for the given target capacity.