# Hashtable is faster than HashMap?

Tags: java

I wrote a standalone program, trying to put 10k elements in a hasmap and hashtable; here I observed hashtable is faster than hashmap for insertion.

HashMap: (Taken time: 31ms)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    long s = System.currentTimeMillis();
    Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
        map.put("i_" + i, i);
    }
    System.out.println("Taken time: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - s));
}
```

HashTable: (Taken time: 15ms)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    long s = System.currentTimeMillis();
    Map<String, Integer> map = new Hashtable<String, Integer>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
        map.put("i_" + i, i);
    }
    System.out.println("Taken time: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - s));
}
```

Is that understanding correct?

Comment: *"Is that understanding correct?"* - This does not ring true.  I suspect that you have made a mistake in the way you are benchmarking.

Comment: Read [How do I write a correct micro-benchmark in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/504103/how-do-i-write-a-correct-micro-benchmark-in-java)

Comment: Please read [Differences between HashMap and Hashtable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40471/differences-between-hashmap-and-hashtable).  Hashtable is obsolete now, but in any case your benchmark may not be that meaningful because it is just one point of data, and who knows what else might be going on in the background JVM.  Actually, Hashtable is synchronized, so I would in general expect HashMap to outperform it.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen The compiler with standard settings should be smart enough to see that no synchronization is needed in this example. Other than that I agree with you.

Comment: @OleV.V. I was more generally referring the OP's benchmark, which may be flawed because of background things like JVM startup time.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, You are correct. When I add both (hashmap & hashtable) put statements in separate methods; i.e, first i call the method hashtable put then hashmap put method. now I can see the clear diff. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry no hashmap is faster. HashMap and Hashtable are vritually identical except that Hashtable is synchronized. This causes Hashtable to perform slower than Hashmap.

PROOF
https://coderanch.com/t/202040/java/Hashtable-HashMap