# Java Hashtable : one key - two value, how to get both of them?

Tags: java, hashtable

My problem is that I have an Hashtable and I end up with some key having two values. I would like to get both of these value, so I can see which one I want and take it.

Here is an exemple :

```
Hashtable<String, String> myTable = new Hashtable<>();
myTable.put("key1", "value1");
myTable.put("key1", "value2");
System.out.println(myTable.get("key1"));
//output : value2
```

How to retrieve both of the value ?

Thank you for your help !

---

EDIT :
In my tests, the HashTable can't store 2 values like this but I assure that in my project where I have a (I believe) code that does the same thing. When, after my algorithm has ran I *System.out.prinln(myTable)* it does show multiple time the same key with differents value.

Comment: Also take a look at this: [hashmap vs. hashtable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40471/differences-between-hashmap-and-hashtable).

Comment: @andrewjames It partially answer. I think the problem comes from the fact that I work with Object and I constantly makes new ones. So it does not consider the keys to be the same thing. So I should probably rewrite this code

Comment: Have you considered using a pair object as a value into your hash table

Comment: I didn't but now I do. It is, I think, the best solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the way to create a HashTable, in your example. You create a HashTable maps a String to a String, then because the value is a String, you cannot expect the table can store multiple values on one key. When you do the second `put` method, it will find the key with value `key1` and replace the previous value which is mapped to this key to the new one.

If you want to store multiple values on one key, think about the list which will hold multiple values for your key. Here is an example to map a key with a type of String to multiple String values:

```java
Hashtable<String, ArrayList<String>> myTable = new Hashtable<>();
ArrayList<String> listValue = new ArrayList<>();
listValue.add("value1");
listValue.add("value2");
myTable.put("key1", listValue); 
System.out.println(myTable.get("key1")); // get all values of the key [value1, value2]
System.out.println(myTable.get("key1").get(0)); // get the first value of this key, value1
System.out.println(myTable.get("key1").get(1)); // get the second value of this key, value2
```

It is recommended to use HashMap over a HashTable.

Answer (score 0):

In HashMap class, put function adds object if it isn't exist, if it's exist just updates the value. You can create another class to keep values;

```
class exampleValue {
    String v1, v2;

    exampleValue() {}
}
```

and

```
HashMap<String, exampleValue> h = new HashMap<>();

exampleValue v = new exampleValue();
v.v1 = "a";
v.v2 = "b";

h.put("key", v);

h.get("key").v1; //returns "a"
h.get("key").v2; //returns "b"
```

Comment: I see the problem. I need to change the second type to something like you said or maybe an Array

Comment: @Virgil Sorry, I couldn't understand. What do you want to do?

Comment: I need change the value type of my Hashtable to something that can store multiple value. Maybe the exampleValue you suggest or an Array.

Comment: Oh, I understand.